# How to generate a normal distribution of a fixed number of random positive integers that sum up to a fixed value

Tags: normal-distribution, python, random-variable

The problem is: randomly generate n positive integers that sum up to a fixed value sum and follow a binomial distribution that approximate a normal distribution.

How would I go about it?

--

Background: there are

- *m* users, each user would use 1 CPU if they are connected to a server.
- *n* servers, each server has a number of unused CPUs (could be zero).

I'm trying to simulate the number of unused CPUs in each server so that it forms a bell curve. And I want the total number of unused CPUs in *n* servers equals to the total CPUs requirement by *m* users.

*n* can be relatively large compared to *m* so if *n* > *m*, I can make *n* = *m*, if that simplifies the problem at all. My problem is not well-defined yet as I'm still thinking of how to select a reasonable median of the distribution.

Comment: If the sum is constant, then what is it that is normally distributed?

Comment: Unless that fixed value is relatively large compared to $n,$ there is no hope that the distribution of the individual integers could approximate Normality anyway.  The combination of conditions in this question just doesn't make any sense.  Could you instead explain the circumstances that motivate it?

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. Such data cannot possibly be normal, by definition. The normal distribution goes to infinity in both directions, your desired data cannot. The normal distribution will eventually take on all possible values on the real number line, but your desired data will only take on whole numbers. I wonder if you want the binomial distribution, which can look [bell curve-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) under the right circumstances.

Comment: Edited just then. Yes I want a binomial distribution that approximate a normal distribution.